# Read locale from cookie

Tags: java, cookies, locale

I have the following scenario:
I want to read a locale from the cookie if any otherwise it takes a default value. If the user change the locale the app should set the passed locale and repaint the app. Basically anytime the locale is null it reads from the cookie. I wondering if reading from cookie can slow too much the application and a caching mechanism is needed. 
Thanks for reply

Comment: You mean java as in javascript?

Comment: I am referring to Java not JavaScript.

Comment: Basically when you log out and log in again it should remember the previous option. That's why I need a cookie

Answer (score 0):

The Cookie is just a HTTP request header, reading it in Java is not expensive, so you should not experience a performance impact.